# Get UserId right after login without reloading page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

In an MVC app `UserId` of current user can be obtained using `WebSecurity.UserId`, but if I do that during the login action it will return -1. The reason for that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13850930) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24071575). Basically the authorization cookie is set during login, but the framework will have access to it no sooner than during the next request. I can somewhat get around not having `UserId` in login action by pulling the user from database based on his\hers name.

However I can't do the same when it comes to external login as I don't have easy access to user's name. For various reasons I need to run two functions that take `UserId` as input and I need to do so right after login using external account. I'd prefer if I could somehow do so within the external login action. So, is there any way to get `UserId` of the user who just logged in without reloading page (redirecting somewhere else)?

I have also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742204/mvc-app-getting-stuck-on-an-error-after-server-restart) problem which I could probably solve if I could get my hands on `UserId` of the currently logged user (even if his authorization cookie was just set during current request). Because of this, I was looking for some more general solution rather than just finding ways to extract user's email from google and facebook callback data during the external login.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263486/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-mvc

This should be helpful.

Comment: @jbutler483 But it isn't. `Membership.GetUser()` returns null, `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` returns -1 and both `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` and `User` return an empty `IPrincipal` object (there is no user data in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semi-solution to my problem, getting user profile after login using external account:

```
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback()
{
    AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback"));
    if (!result.IsSuccessful)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
    }
    if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
    {
        var db = new MyDataClassesDataContext();
        var user = db.ExecuteQuery<UserProfile>("SELECT TOP 1 up.* FROM [dbo].webpages_OAuthMembership oam JOIN [dbo].UserProfile up ON (up.UserId = oam.UserId) WHERE oam.ProviderUserId = '" + result.ProviderUserId + "'").FirstOrDefault();
        // Do your post login stuff here
        return RedirectToAction("SomewhereAfterLogin");
    }
    // Here goes creating a new account in case external wasn't in the system before
}
```

This however doesn't solve the problem of server having rare random restarts that cause authorization cookie to disappear where I don't know user's id without making a redirect (which causes problems in my app as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742204/mvc-app-getting-stuck-on-an-error-after-server-restart)).